# Am I using "namesake" correctly?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am writing an essay about (among other things) Gutenberg's printing press and [Project Gutenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Gutenberg). I want to say something along the lines of "Gutenberg's press was so popular that current things are named after him." I tried the following. Am I using *namesake* correctly?

> As evidenced ahead, Gutenberg’s invention was so popular that he is still a popular namesake.

I want to keep *namesake* in there because I think it sounds cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namesake) it appears that your usage is a bit off. But you can keep it in there with a small modification:

> As evidenced ahead, Gutenberg’s invention was so popular it is still common to see his namesake.

Comment: Namesake is normally used for another person. eg. "Bush's presidency reminded us of his namesake Washington." Eponymous would be better - as in Tim's answer

Answer (score 3):

You might like to use 'eponym' though strictly that refers to the use of a name as a word: 'Project Gutenberg is named after the eponymous printer'.  Still pretty cool.